# How to convert the following simple Nginx rewrite conditions and rules to Apache .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver

I want to convert the following Ngnix rewrite rules and conditions to Apache .htaccess, but I was not able to successfully do it.

```
location /app/ {
  if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^ /app/index.html break;
  }
}

location ~ /app/account/(.*?)$ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ /app/pay/(.*?)$ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? Is it already enabled from your Apache config?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, based on your shown code only. Also I am no expert of nginx, but I am trying my best here :) Please make sure you clear your browser cache before you test your URLs.

Obviously if you could give us samples of URLs with logic of from which url to which url you want to rewrite/redirect then it would have been easier to understand it better and would have been helpful in testing too.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##First rule here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /app/index.html [L]

##Second rule here....
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/account/(.*)/?$ index.php?$1 [L]

##Third rule here....
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/pay/(.*)/?$  index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer.
Do I need to stop and restart my PHP server?

Comment: @mnrafg, you could restart apache once not an issue(be careful if its a live environment), let me know how it goes?

Comment: @mnrafg, Hi could you please do let me know if this solution has helped you? thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, my server issue isn't resolved until now, but I really appreciate your help and thanks again.

Comment: @mnrafg, could you please do let me know what sample/example URLs you are trying to hit. Show samples/examples like FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect/rewrite? That will give me better understanding of your question and I could edit my rules then if needed, let me know cheers.